# lxml xpath.// and // difference

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

```
 <multi-routing-engine-item>

        <re-name>n</re-name>

        <zones-information xmlns="http://xml48/juzones" j:s="de">
            <zones-security>
                <zones-security-zonename>A</zones-security-zonename>
                <zones-security-interfaces>
                    <zones-security-interface-name>reth2.66</zones-security-interface-name>
                    <zones-security-interface-name>2.68</zones-security-interface-name>
                </zones-security-interfaces>
            </zones-security>
            <zones-security>        
                <zones-security-zonename>B</zones-security-zonename>
```

question1:

```
 >>> response_zone.xpath("//zones-information/zones-security[//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()")
    ['A', 'B', 'C']
    >>> 
    >>> response_zone.xpath("//zones-information/zones-security[.//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()")
    ['A']
```

what is the difference between .// and // in this context. A little bit confused.

question2:

```
>>> response_zone.xpath(".//zones-security[.//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()")
['A']
>>> response_zone.xpath("//zones-security[.//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()") 
['A']
```

in question2 , they have same result.....

I am confused by this . need help.

Comment: `.` refers to the current node. And if a query begins with a `/` or `//` it's relative to the root of the document. `//` goes through all descendants. Put that together and what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Read this for xPath https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath =)

`.` - s short for `self::node()`, reference for current node

`//` - is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, search inside all nodes on all layers

`.//` - search from current node on all layers

`./` search from current node 1 layer below

**so when you do:**

`//something[.//another]` - `something` that has `another` inside on any layer

`//something[./another]` - `something` that has `another` as child

`//something[//another]` - `something` , but somewhere in the file `another` should be too [not just inside `something`, but anywhere]

`//something//another` - `another` that has `something` as parent on any layer

`//something/another` - `something` that direct parent`another`

`//something.//another` - error, as syntax is not correct, use just `//` instead =)

when you just start locator with `//` or `.//` - there's no difference as starting point is root document element, so it will search inside whole file anyway

Comment: //something[//another] :if it can find another in somewhere, xpath respond with all the value under //something .like what I get :response_zone.xpath("//zones-information/zones-security[//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()")
    ['A', 'B', 'C']          .Am I correct?

Comment: I want to understand why it responds all zones-secur‌​ity-zonename/text() in case I use  //something[//another]

Comment: because you are searching not from current node,  use `.//` instead=) that's just how xpath works, i'm not sure why they implemented it in this way. But using this you can, for example, get some value that is totally not related to current node (for example some pages amount)  and use it in current node. I think that was the main reason.

Comment: yes, I know I seach not from current node         [//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66'] ,but the whole path is :response_zone.xpath("//zones-information/zones-security[//zones-security-interface-name[text()='reth2.66']]/zones-security-zonename/text()")  . How to understand this?